# Paradox DateTime Importing to SQL

Tags: sql, paradox

I do not believe this is possible but thought I may as well ask, before I go through each row correcting dates in this paradox table.

Issue I have is:  I am importing a Paradox table through the SQL Interface (right click Import) however some of the DateTime Fields in Paradox are for example 17/11/0201.  Paradox allows this whereas SQL Does not and cancels and gives me the row number this error occurs on.  I have to go through and correct manually and re-run the import.  Is there a way to fix this? Automate it?

Thanks!

Comment: One suggestion: import into a temporary table with the 'date columns' as string fields. Then format the 'temporary string date' columns into  'acceptable date format'?

Comment: Nice! Good shout, how do I change the column type back to DateTime with the data in this column? Cheers

Comment: The format looks to be 'dd/mm/' then something which produces a 'funny' year'. You need to look at the 'paradox' database and see what those 'years' actually are and how they are being output as they are. Then just use format them into standard sql 'date' format strings. examples: [sql-date-function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-date-functions.htm). Or create your own 'export' routines in the 'paradox' database that output standard 'sql' date strings (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS).

Comment: Paradox export: this may be useful: [Program to convert Paradox databases](http://pxlib.sourceforge.net/pxview/documentation.php?manpage=pxview). Found via 'Internet search': 'paradox database csv dates'.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Finally done it